# Yolov4 onnxruntime C++

Tags: c++, yolo, onnx, tensorrt, onnxruntime

I need to deploy a yolov4 inference model and I want to use onnxruntime with tensorRT backend. I don't know how to post process yolov4 detection result in C++. I have a sample written in python but I can not find C++ sample.

https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/vision/object_detection_segmentation/yolov4

Is there a sample to know how to process yolov4 onnx result ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we have built something similar. For now we have only yolov3 with onnxruntime in C++ but we are testing yolov4 and will be avaiable in our next release. If you want have a look here https://github.com/ai4prod/ai4prod.